# Simple ListView in android not working in android

Tags: android, android-listview

I have made a simple android ListView demo but its not working my code is below:

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" >
</TextView>
```

**main.java**

```
    package com.example.mylist;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.ListActivity;
    import android.database.DataSetObserver;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
        static final String[] list = new String[] { "Awesome", "New", "Retro",
                "Rock", "Pop", "Bollywood", "hollywood" };

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_main,
                    list));
            ListView listvw = getListView();
            listvw.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

            listvw.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            ((TextView) v).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });

        }

    }
```

**logcat**

```
07-29 14:16:21.335: E/AndroidRuntime(27347): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-29 14:16:21.335: E/AndroidRuntime(27347): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mylist/com.example.mylist.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
07-29 14:16:21.335: E/AndroidRuntime(27347):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
07-29 14:16:21.335: E/AndroidRuntime(27347):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
07-29 14:16:21.335: E/AndroidRuntime(27347):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
07-29 14:16:21.335: E/AndroidRuntime(27347):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
07-29 14:16:21.335: E/AndroidRuntime(27347):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-29 14:16:21.335: E/AndroidRuntime(27347):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-29 14:16:21.335: E/AndroidRuntime(27347):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
07-29 14:16:21.335: E/AndroidRuntime(27347):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-29 14:16:21.335: E/AndroidRuntime(27347):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-29 14:16:21.335: E/AndroidRuntime(27347):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-29 14:16:21.335: E/AndroidRuntime(27347):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-29 14:16:21.335: E/AndroidRuntime(27347):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-29 14:16:21.335: E/AndroidRuntime(27347): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
07-29 14:16:21.335: E/AndroidRuntime(27347):    at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:243)
07-29 14:16:21.335: E/AndroidRuntime(27347):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:254)
07-29 14:16:21.335: E/AndroidRuntime(27347):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1862)
07-29 14:16:21.335: E/AndroidRuntime(27347):    at com.example.mylist.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
```

pls help me...!

Comment: Set an id for TextView  and try this setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.main, R.id.textView, list);

Comment: Still same prblm...remaining...dear.

Comment: The logcat says it all: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'`. Add a `ListView` with id `android.R.id.list` to your xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    package com.ListView;

    public class ListViewActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener{
   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private String[] 
    Name={"Destop","CPU","Pendrive","Mouse","Keyboard","Harddisk","Cardreader","MotherBord"};
    ListView l1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    l1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    l1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,Name));
    l1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
   }

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
        long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Toast.makeText(this, Name[arg2].toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Toast.makeText(this, "Item Not Selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just comment this line in your code. Then i hope it work

```
// setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

and do not call onclick try this way

```
listvw.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
        // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
        ((TextView) view).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

and import this two

```
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
```

Comment: Still the same problem remaining..!

Comment: do not call onclick on list view call onitem click try my code

Answer (score 0):

You're supplying a custom layout but not defining a `ListView` in it.

Change your `main.xml` (I assume it's either `main.xml` or `activity_main.xml`, your code refers to one but you post the other) to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp" />
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html

> ListActivity has a default layout that consists of a single, full-screen list in the center of the screen. However, if you desire, you can customize the screen layout by setting your own view layout with setContentView() in onCreate(). To do this, your own view MUST contain a ListView object with the id "@android:id/list" (or list if it's in code)

Alternatively, as the documentation suggests, remove the `setContentView()` call if you have no plans to customise the layout.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
     <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/hello" /> 
    <ListView android:id="@+id/listView1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" /> 
  </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please, don't give multiple answers to the same question. Instead, you can edit you existing answer. Besides, if you just provide code in the answer, it is pretty hard to follow. Have a look at [How to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer)